# How do I send user inputs to a database using the forms feature in swift UI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-form

I’m new to swift UI and programming in general. I’ve learnt the basics so far and now I want to be able to setup a simple form in my app. I can design the form no problem. But I’m not sure what function to call CIA the button action or the code to get that information from the user to a database. Can someone help to explain how to set that up and which database to use to collect the user information?

Comment: There are a number of ways to store data in a database -- most likely you'll want to look into CoreData, but there's also Firebase, Realm, etc. There are also some non-database solutions, like storing in UserDefaults or a JSON file. There are *plenty* of CoreData SwiftUI tutorials out there that you kind find via searching. Here's a good starting point: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-combine-core-data-and-swiftui

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Comment: By database, do you mean cloud database(saving information to the server) or persistent data storage(storing information locally on your device)
Like @jnpdx said, you could use Realm and Core Data for local storage, while you could use Firebase for storing information in the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't set the database up for you, as each database has its unique ways of doing so. However, I am giving you a basic structure that would help you link your SwiftUI view to the back-end(your database).

Setting up your form

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var firstName = ""
    @State var lastName = ""
    @State var age = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter First Name", text: $firstName)
        TextField("Enter Last Name", text: $lastName)
        TextField("Age", text: $age)
        Button(action: {
            addUser(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, age: Int(age) ?? 0)
        }) {
            Text("Save to database")
        }
    }
}
```

Saving result to back-end:

```
import CoreData

func addUser(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
/*   
     code here would be using Core Data structure
     do not copy paste, only used as reference
*/
    let newUser = User(context: context)
    newUser.firstName = firstName
    newUser.lastName = lastName
    newUser.age = age
    
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Successfully saved to Core Data.")
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}
```

Keep in mind that you would have to do your own research on how to save results using your own database. The code in `addUser()` would not work if you are using something other than Core Data. In your case, I would suggest you to try Firebase and perhaps, you could use Firebase Firestore as it seems like it suits your needs.